# Resize WIndow across two monitors always rescale to one monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor

I cant resize a window across two monitors anymore in Ubuntu 22.04.

I put the monitor to the left side of the left monitor. Than I pull the right end of the window over the first monitor to the right side of the right monitor. When I lose the mouse the window is maximized on the left monitor. I would like to send pictures but they are to big (greater than 2MB)